# DIP switch on Atmega32, are external pull-ups neccessary?

Tags: digital-logic, atmega, pullup

[image]

I'm connecting a DIP switch to an Atmega32 as shown in the diagram above. This works well in my application so far. However the common opinion seems to be that external pullups are necessary for a more robust implementation / less EMI susceptibility.

How can I decide whether or not the internal pullup resistors are sufficient for my application? Or is it safe to say "when in doubt use external pullup resistors"?

Answer (score 3):

Internal pullups are sufficient when the voltage on the input will be within the voltage thresholds given in the datasheet and when current consumption meets desired goals.

If the connection to ground is relatively high-impedance or if current consumption is too high then a larger external pullup (and disabling of the internal pullup) is required.

Answer (score 1):

The internal pullup resistors on the [ATMega32](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc2503.pdf) are between 20K and 50K.

There are certainly situations where 20K may be too low (perhaps because of current consumption) or 50K may be too high (because of EMI or leakage considerations).

50K should still be okay for a DIPswitch mounted in reasonable proximity on the same PCB in most situations, particularly if the circuit is earthed relative to the case and/or there is a ground pour or ground plane.

If in doubt you can always allow for a couple pullup packages that are not populated. It would also allow you to test the circuit with arbitrary pullup values such as 200K to see if you can detect any susceptibility.

[image]